# How to troubleshoot/diagnose an oven that won't heat past a certain point?

Tags: repair, oven, troubleshooting

Our ovens (double-stacked Nutone Hotpoint circa 1960s) are **old**:

[image]

[image]

[image]

About 2 months ago, we noticed that the bottom one - which had been running great for years - wouldn't get any hotter than just "*kind of warm*". No matter what we set it to (Bake 500 degrees, Broil, etc.) and no matter how long we waited, the bottom oven would never get anywhere past 100 degrees or so. No big whoop, because we still had the top one working fine.

Well now the top one is doing the same exact thing which means we're out of a usable oven. This is a very big whoop.

Ideally, I'd like to troubleshoot, diagnose & repair the ovens. I just find it strange that these 2 ovens have been running strong since the 1960s and now they both go within a few months of each other.

I'm not sure where to even begin troubleshooting. For one, they certainly could use a cleaning, so I think I'd like to start there. But I have to ask: what steps/processes should I go through to figure out what is going on with these?

Comment: I can only offer a general idea that if both the bottom and top heating elements to the oven are acting the same way, I would start with trying to identify where the temperature sensor exists and check or replace that.  Odds are the reason they both failed about the same time and are exhibiting the same behavior is because something in both has reached the end of the road.

Comment: Thanks @treeNinja - so would these ovens *share* the same temp sensor? If that's the case, then I could understand how it would affect them both, but still strange that the sensor would continue working for one for several months... any ideas as to how I would access the temp sensor? Thanks again!

Comment: I would envision two distinct sensors, one for each oven.  Generally it is something that sits within the oven itself. That's pretty much the extent of my knowledge however.  Hopefully someone else here can provide some more input.

Comment: Could be a bad element, which can  be checked by measuring the resistance across the element. Compare the value you get to the specifications on the oven, or in the manufactures documentation. The more likely culprit, is a bad thermostat. Not sure how to replace the thermostat in your specific oven, but you should be able to find documentation on the Internet.

Comment: Thanks @Tester101 - 2 quick followups: (1) did you mean "...measuring the *resistance* across the element...", or did you actually mean **residence**? If so, what is "residence"? And (2) What's the difference between: (a) thermocouple, (b) temp sensor and (c) thermostat? Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, yes I meant **resistance** (phone auto fill decided I didn't want to type that). A thermocouple converts heat to an electrical signal, and is a type of temperature sensor. A thermostat opens and closes a switch based on temperature, and uses some form of temperature sensor.

Comment: Thanks again @Tester101 - and I guess its safe to assume that both ovens would have their own thermostats, both of which use their own thermocouples/temp sensors (so 2 thermostats, and 2 temp sensors)? Any explanation as to why both went within a few months of each other? Just seems odd; I guess I was expecting the ovens to share something in common with each other, and that the share "thing" started giving out a few months ago (hence the bottom oven going), and is now finally shot (hence the 2nd oven). Ideas?

Comment: They're both the same age, right?  So why would it be odd for them to die around the same time?  Try to find a schematic for the oven either inside the oven, or online.  That will tell you exactly what components are involved, and then you can start testing each one.

Comment: Have you checked the breaker? Have you reset it a couple of times? After that, I'd inspect the heating elements and thermostats for any obvious decay. Then disconnect power and inspect the wiring on the back of the control panel, just to see if anything is obvious. If none of those, then I'd try replacing one of the thermostat probes. If that works, I'd replace the other. Alternatively, I'd consider a used replacement, this type of unit gets replaced all the time in kitchen upgrades and they show up in good shape at the local Habitat for Humanity store fairly regularly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that coiled up wire at the top right is the thermocouple. Do I see a silver tip thing on the end of it? You can splice thermocouple wires if you use ceramic wire nuts, otherwise you have to trace that back to behind the control panel. Here's some good info at [Appliance411](http://www.appliance411.com/faq/replace-oven-sensor.shtml). I'm not to keen on electric ovens, but with the door open and perhaps a fan blowing in, I'd like to think you'd see the elements glow at least briefly in order to eliminate element or control knob problems.

Comment: Thanks @Mazura - so are you suggesting that the problem is with the *thermocouple* or with the *temp sensor*? Or are these units one in the same?

Comment: It's the same thing and the only reason other than element failure or a knob issue. Doesn't sound like a lose power line as they failed independently. @smeeb

Comment: Thanks again @Mazura - **can you please confirm** that there my problem is one of three possible things: (1) bad thermocouple, (2) bad element or (3) bad knob? If so, are there any other articles/blogs/etc. that you can point me to for troubleshooting the element and knob? I'd like to troubleshoot everything that is a potential candidate and hopefully find the rotten egg in the bunch. Thanks again!

Comment: I can't really confirm any of this guess work, but a thermocouple is the first thing I'd try to replace. @smeeb