# Why would the stove and broiler work, but not the oven?

Tags: oven, propane

I have a little 20" wide Holiday Propane Oven (Don't know the model number). Right now the oven is the only thing that is not working. The stove top, and broiler work, but the oven doesn't heat up. When I turn the oven on there is no smell. I tried turning the knob to broiler, and the flames kick on so from there, I tried turning it back to the oven temps, but it shuts off after about 30 seconds. Any help fixing this is appreciated. These things are expensive to buy new.

Answer (score 2):

It's either the knob or (much more likely) the thermocouple.

Related: [Oven wont heat past a certain point](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/48730/how-to-troubleshoot-diagnose-an-oven-that-wont-heat-past-a-certain-point/48741#48741).

Comment: I'll have to look into the thermocouple. The broiler is on the same knob as the oven. Thanks!